# Android Studio - zip v/s exe

Tags: android, android-studio

I've two main questions :

1) What are the differences between **ZIP** and **EXE** version of Android Studio (Except the portability) ?

2) Does it affect the working speed of the **IDE** ?

Comment: As usual (not always but many do) in Windows apps, you are given the ability of having a self-installer and a "core files" version. The latter requires you to have already installed the required components and it's most suited for manual upgrades, or in cases where you need to have more control on what is installed and what is not. Generally, I prefer the self-contained installers. The speed of the IDE is the same, since the executable doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In case of performance there is no difference between ZIP and EXE.**

The recommended **EXE** version is *larger in size* and needed to be installed using installation wizard. It will download the SDK during installation. **So the installation process will take a big amount of time.**

The zipped version doesn't include the SDK. So after downloading you just need to extract it. And this can be portable as well.

**Which one you should select:** 
*If you have a backup of updated SDK or if you can collect it from someones PC, then you can download the zipped version without the SDK and then show the path of SDK. It will save your time and bandwidth. If you don't have backup of SDK then go for fresh installation*

**NOTE: There isn't any performance related difference between this two.**

Comment: I find that the ZIP is larger in size `(android-studio-ide-141.2117773-windows.exe 321791384 bytes, android-studio-ide-141.2117773-windows.zip 344407592 bytes)` [Android Studio Downloads](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other)

Comment: You may find two version of **Zip**.  One of them is *no SDK tools included* another one includes the SDK tool. But the sdk tool needed to be updated after installation.

Comment: 'plus 1' for the NOTE :)

Comment: No, the two ZIP versions: _SDK Tools Only_ and _IDE only_ :)